# Datasource method not calling in iOS 4.3 but working in iOS 5 and later

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, xcode4.2

I have a UIViewController object VCobject. In my view will appear method i had written the following code.

```
    VCobject = [[GCView alloc] init]; 

    VCobject.dataSource = self;
    VCobject.delegate = self;
```

The datasource method is calling in iOS 5.0 and in 5.1. But is not calling in iOS 4.3. I am using Xcode 4.3.2.

Any one have any idea, pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 5 has [changed the way `viewWillAppear` is called](http://gamesfromwithin.com/view-controller-notification-changes-on-ios5). To make sure that this is a case setup a breakpoint inside your `viewWillAppear` method.